# member.name for member in guild.members only prints bot name, even with intents enabled in the code

Tags: discord, discord.py

i'm following the RealPython tutorial on how to make a discord bot and have come across the issue where my code only prints the name of the bot, but not mine. i've seen solutions where you enable priveleged gateway intents in the developer portal and add the discord.Client(intents=intents) code to the beginning of your code, so i did, but the problem still persists. i'm not getting any error or anything, just that only my bot's name prints.
please let me know if i missed out anything or if there's another issue i need to solve. thanks!

here's my code:

```py
# bot.py
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lines where you assign a `discord.Client` to `client`.

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
# and
client = discord.Client()
```

The first line is done properly with the intents. The second line, however, makes a new `discord.Client` object with *no intents*. Remove one of these lines and make sure intents are enabled on the line you keep.

Comment: i deleted the second line so i'm now left with intents = discord.Intents.all() but it's still giving me the same output